# What is the difference between inline-level elements and inline elements?

Tags: html, css, frontend

[In this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements#inline), they compare *inline* elements to block-level elements?

I notice they did they used *inline* elements and not *inline-level* elements.

What is the difference?

Comment: It's best not to use this particular dichotomy, which stems from the obsolete HTML4 specification. Concepts like inline, inline-level, block, and block-level are better left to CSS where they are much more tightly defined, and are all different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline elements is a shorter version of inline-level elements. In the same way, block-level elements can also be referred to as block elements. So there is no difference between them and can be used interchangeably.

The following are quotes from [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#glossary) that confirms this:

> **inline-level**:
> Content that participates in inline layout. Specifically, inline-level boxes and text runs.

> **inline**:
> Used as a shorthand for inline box or inline-level box where unambiguous, or as an adjective meaning inline-level. The latter usage is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Inline level and inline elements are the same, check this link:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

You will see the link content "block-level elements" if you click it, it will take you to a page named "Inline elements", that's means they are the same.